# Apache folder and files returing 404 Not Found when should be returning 403 Forbidden on Linux

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have made a custom folder within WordPress' `uploads` directory to house some downloadable files, however I don't want these to be directly accessible, they should only be accessible via a script for example.

To accomplish this I simply put a `.htaccess` file in the respective folder containing:

```
Deny from all
```

My development environment is Windows and this was working fine, both the folder and file returned a `403 Forbidden` and I was able to force download the file via a script.

Now I have uploaded the site to a staging server that is running on Linux (RedHat I think?), Apache as well, but for both the folder and the file it returns a `404 Not Found` and hence the file download also fails.

What am I missing here? Why is it acting differently? Should I be putting some different/extra in the `.htaccess` file?

**Edit:** I just noticed that whilst it IS stating it is a `404`, it is redirecting to a `403.shtml` file.

Comment: Try adding `ErrorDocument 403 default` at top of this .htaccess

Comment: That worked somewhat, but not fully. It shows a forbidden page, but file download file fails, consequently because `file_exists($file_path)` is returning `false`. I have also just noticed, before I added what you suggested that whilst it WAS stating it was a `404`, it was redirecting to a `403.shtml` file.

Comment: `file_exists($file_path) is returning false` that means file system paths are different on new Linux host. May be there are broken symlinks.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the path was wrong, was caused by the staging server installation not being in the root dir, which caused an issue when utilising the `ABSPATH` constant in WordPress plus getting the path from `parse_url`. :)